# Java - Stuck on one final point - trying to replay the program

Tags: java, loops, joptionpane

I am new to Java and working on the first assignment of the term. I simply have to run 3 of those math trick games where the user thinks of a number and does some calculations to it and then the program guesses the original number. I am stuck because I want the program to ask the user if he wants to play again when he is done going through it, but unfortunately whatever I try just creates another problem. There are 3 "difficulty" levels. but as long as i can get the one working without any errors than it is easy enough to create two other math questions.

My problem arises when i tried to implement the playAgain() method and a while loop. Unfortunately, now when the user presses cancel to quit the game it asks  again "would you like to play again" and you need to press NO for it to actually quit.

It seems like such an obvious answer to this, but i am stuck and was hoping to get some feed back on where I am going wrong and what to do to find a solution.

I have included the code I have so far below:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class AssignmentBeta
{

    public static void main(String [] args) 
    {

            int answer =  JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog
                          (null, "Would you Like to Play a Math 
                          Guessing Game?", "Play a Game!", 
                          JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);


            if(answer == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
            {
                String gamelevel = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                    (null,"please choose a difficulty level",
                     "Choosing The Level", 
                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null , 
                    new Object[] {"Amazingly Hard!", 
                    "Boringly Mediocre", "Shockingly Easy"},
                    "Shockingly Easy");

                    if(gamelevel==null)
                    {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Goodbye"); //CANCEL
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    Rungame(gamelevel);
                    }

            }
            else
            {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Goodbye"); //CANCEL
            }

            //playAgain=playAgain(); -- this is where i am implementing it

    }

    public static void Rungame(String gamelevel)
    {

        if(gamelevel.equals("Amazingly Hard!"))
        {
            System.out.print("Dark side of the Moon");
        }


        else if(gamelevel.equals("Boringly Mediocre"))
        {

            int age =0;
            boolean retry = true;

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "I Will Guess
                     Your Age!");
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Multiply the 
                    FIRST DIGIT of your AGE by 5.");
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Add THREE to
                    the number.");
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "DOUBLE UP the 
                    number.");
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Now ADD the 
                    SECOND DIGIT of your age to the number.");

            while(retry || !(age > 8 && age <= 105))
                {

                    String number = "";
                    while(number.isEmpty())
                    {
                                number =  JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                                        null,
                                        "Please enter the NUMBER and I 
                                         will return your age!",
                                        "Multiplication Testing", 
                                        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

                        if(number == null)
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
                            "Goodbye"); //CANCEL
                        }

                        else if (number.isEmpty())
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You 
                            didn't enter a value."); //NO VALUE 
                        }

                    }

                    age = ( Integer.parseInt(number) - 6);


                    if(!(age >8 && age <=105))
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Don't 
                            lie, that is all but impossible!");
                        }

                    else
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are 
                            Only " + age + " Years Young!!" );
                            retry = false;  
                        }

                }
        }

        else
        {
            System.out.print("suck my kiss");
        }

    }

    public static boolean playAgain()
    {
    int answer = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you want to 
                 play again?", "Continue?", 
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if(answer == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you kindly for your help,

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in your IDE debugger? That will help you find the issue and you will learn something in the process. Please do that first.

Comment: Perhaps have a look for [`do-while`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) loops

Comment: the program compiles fine, and I have tested the program many times, and I know what the problem is each new time I run it. I can even locate it, but whatever i do to fix it, (ie. create another boolean and a while loop) another unwanted error is created.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Your still alive? Haven't seen a post of you quite a long time. Remembering the times when you were really active here on SO ;)

Comment: @MouseEvent I've been lurking for awhile, just been busy doing actual "work" :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer cheers mate, i put a do while loop right after the if(answer == ..) and ended it before the final else bracket and it seems to do the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apply do-while loop in main method just like below and try.

```
if(answer == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
{

do {
   String gamelevel = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog
       (null,"please choose a difficulty level",
       "Choosing The Level", 
       JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null , 
       new Object[] {"Amazingly Hard!", 
       "Boringly Mediocre", "Shockingly Easy"},
       "Shockingly Easy");

       if(gamelevel==null)
       {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Goodbye"); //CANCEL
       }
       else {
           Rungame(gamelevel);
       }
} while(playAgain());
}
else
{
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Goodbye"); //CANCEL
}
```

Comment: you have an extra { before the else, but otherwise, yes this is what I did just now as well after MadProgrammer gave me the tip!

thank you kindly!